# Simple vector calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

I found a calculation in my textbook as following:

If $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy
$\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{1}<0$ and $\boldsymbol{y}>\boldsymbol{0}$, then
$\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{y}<0$

Although this result is intuitive, I'm not sure by what algebraic procedure I can obtain this.

Comment: $y>0$ means that all its elements are strictly positive ?

Comment: Yes. Its elements are strictly positive.

Comment: take $x=(4,-5)$ and $y=(5,2)$, it does not work.

Comment: It turns out that I misunderstood the textbook. $\boldsymbol{y}=k\boldsymbol{1}$ and $k>0$Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This isn't true. Imagine $\boldsymbol{x}=\left({\begin{array}c -2 \\ 1\end{array}}\right)$ and $\boldsymbol{y}=\left({\begin{array}c 1 \\ 3\end{array}}\right)$.

Then $\boldsymbol{x}.\boldsymbol{1}=\left({\begin{array}c -2 \\ 1\end{array}}\right).\left({\begin{array}c 1 \\ 1\end{array}}\right)=-2\times1+1\times1=-1<0$

and $\boldsymbol{y}=\left({\begin{array}c 1 \\ 3\end{array}}\right)>\left({\begin{array}c 0 \\ 0\end{array}}\right)$

but $\boldsymbol{x}.\boldsymbol{y}=\left({\begin{array}c -2 \\ 1\end{array}}\right).\left({\begin{array}c 1 \\ 3\end{array}}\right)=-2\times1+1\times3=1>0$.